# Div not extending to width of parent

Tags: html, css

I've got a navigation bar that I want positioned at the top of the viewport. I have my nav wrapper enclosed by a header container, enclosed by my main wrapper.

For a reason I don't understand, my header container is not behaving as expected. If I set its width to 100%, it stretches far beyond the main wrapper to the right. I then removed the "width: 100%" because I read several places that divs by default stretch to fill the width of their parent. When I removed the width: 100%, then the header container shrinks to a size somewhat less than the main wrapper.

Any thoughts on what could be the problem here? Here's the code followed by a jsfiddle:

```
HTML
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="headercontainer">
    <div class="nav-wrap">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="">news</a></li>
            <li><a href="">blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- end nav-wrap-->
</div> <!-- end headercontainer -->

<div>
    <font size="6em">
    <br><br>
    this is the main wrapper with filler<br>
    this is the story filler<br>
    this is the story filler<br>
    this is the story filler<br>
    this is the story filler<br>
    this is the story filler<br>
    this is the story filler<br>
    this is the story filler<br>
    this is the story filler<br>
    this is the story filler<br>
    this is the story filler<br>
    </font>
</div>
```

```
CSS
html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px auto;
background: #e1e1e1;
font: normal 400 1em/1.5 sans-serif;
}

.main-wrap {
display: block;
background-color: white;
min-height: 100%;
width: 70%;
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.headercontainer {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #990033;
display: block;
z-index: 100;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.nav-wrap {
padding: 14px 10px 12px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-bottom: thin solid #000000;
background-color: white;
overflow:hidden;
text-align: left;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: .8em;
color: green;
}

ul{
margin: 0px;
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/strudelmedia/01gr4555/10/

Answer (score 3):

Percentages in `width` are resolved relatively to the width of the containing block of the element.

Usually, that containing block is the nearest block ancestor, probably the parent.

However, for fixed positioned elements, the containing block is the viewport. (*)

Therefore, `width: 100%` makes it as wide as the viewport.

(*) There are some exceptions, like transformed ancestors. But if you use that, the element won't be fixed anymore when you scroll the document.

Comment: Thanks for that useful info! So the followups would be: 1) why, when the width is set to 100%, does the div line up on the left side of the parent, but extend out to the viewport only on the right side? 2) why, when I leave the width out completely, does it only stretch to about 80% of the parent? and finally 3) how would I be able to achieve my goal of having this sticky navbar fill out the width of the main wrapper? You can view the above jsfiddle to see what I'm talking about. And thanks!

Comment: [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) 1) Because you didn't set neither `left` nor `right` properties. Therefore, its left side is positioned at its static position, i.e. the position it would have if it weren't fixed. 2) Because you didn't set `width` nor `left` and `right`. Then the width is calculated with the [shrink-to-fit algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float). The 80% is by chance, it depends on the content. 3) I would use sticky positioning ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/01gr4555/13/)), but not all browsers support it yet.

Answer (score 0):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning) on positioning:

> Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning, with the exception that the element's containing block is the **viewport**.

Therefore parent block is not the `div.main-wrap`, but rather UA's viewport, that's where 100% are calculated from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/01gr4555/12/

Just change this in your `CSS`

```
.headercontainer {
    background-color: #990033;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 0;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 70%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try

> position: sticky;

so you solve the parent width problem and your nav will stick to the top of the page; not exactly what you are looking for, but it might work for you.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky `position: sticky` is mainly unsupported by most browsers.